# Bootstrap 5 grid system with ngPrime Splitter control

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, primeng

I am using ngPrime's Splitter control on the page, splitter divides the page into two halves. On both sides of the pages, I will have some HTML elements in Bootstrap's grid system.

What I am noticing is the grid system only works on "browser's" window size, is there any way to use the grid system on Splitter's movement?

EDITED: **Is there a way to use the Bootstrap grid system with "Container queries" instead of "media queries" on the selected page?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to upvote [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/37807)